# What this HTML code means?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've viewed in some source code and found something like this:

```
<div class="classname {height: 300px; width: 200px}"></div>
```

I know that element styling is available by using the `style=""` attribute.

Can you please tell me what this code means?

Comment: This looks like a wrong framework call to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means nothing per se in the HTML specification. The website you were looking at was probably using some javascript code which interprets this `class` attribute and performs some actions based on the values it has parsed. Without javascript this does nothing. In HTML the `class` attribute is used to specify a CSS classname to be associated to this element.

For example the [jQuery.validate](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) plugin uses similar technique allowing you to specify inline validation rules. Actually the plugin uses `data-*` attributes instead of `class` which is semantically more correct for those kind of tasks.

Comment: No, it's not different. It would have been semantically more correct to use `data-*` attributes instead for this kind of tasks. They are designed exactly for this purpose and allow you to associate some additional metadata to a DOM element.

Comment: I think the validate plugin uses `data-` attributes nowadays like any good library should do. There is absolutely no valid reason to put metadata in the `class` attribute anymore.